# What is mean by [1 -1] Filter?

Tags: filters

While studying about Wavelet Transform, I'm confused as why this is called a [1 -1] Filter , Here is what i'm talking about.

> In this hypothetical example the student does fairly well the first
>   half of the     term then neglects his or her studies for the last
>   half. Thus the exam scores     for the term were 80%, 80%, 80%, 80%,
>   0%, 0%, 0%, and 0%*     We can tell the average of all the scores
>   (40%) and when the scores “tanked”     after the 4th exam just by
>   looking. Knowing the answer in advance, however,     is a good way to
>   learn and to verify the wavelet transforms. Then we     can use them
>   with confidence on real-world data where we can’t simply     “eyeball”
>   the final values.
>
> We will now walk through the CWT process step by step using the
>   simplest     of the wavelet filters on this example. We begin by
>   comparing the humble Haar wavelet filter, [1 –1], with the data as
>   shown

```
80 80 80 80 0 0 0 0
```

If We now keep subtracting each value from the next value we will eventually get,

```
[0, 0, 0, 80, 0, 0, 0]
```

Now If I want to stretch the Filter to three points i.e If the filter is stretched from [1 –1] to [1 0 –1].

How will I calculate these points as I did in case of two point Filter where i simply subtract each value from the next value ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have the same book as you. :-)

The [1 -1] filter is a a simple differentiator, also known as, the Haar mother wavelet. You need to understand convolution to understand what he is saying. On the first level, you convolve your signal with [1 -1]. Then on the next level, you convole your signal with [1 0 -1], etc. That is all the [CWT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_wavelet_transform) is doing. (Look at [convolution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convolution) first). If you understand that well, you can understand CWT very easily.

Comment: Thank you very much, 
P.S: this is the best Wavelet book i've ever found  :)
There is another book 'Wavelet Toolbox for Use with Matlab' by Michel Misiti,Yves Misiti,Georges Oppenheim,Jean-Michel Poggi and that is great too

Comment: could you tell me why we padded zero on both side of the original sequence (80 80 80 80 0 0 0 0) -> (0 80 80 80 80 0 0 0 0 0) when using haar wavelet ? @Mohammad

Comment: ...This, again, has to do with the convolution. The author is showing you the convolution as a series of sliding dot products. I would *highly* recommend you read and understand convolution before doing the CWT or Wavelets in general.